# Datesbetween function not working with harvested slicers in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm new to Power BI and trying to build a measure to calculate no. of records which have dates between week start date and week end date.

I have created a slicer with calendar dates and harvesting the dates into two measure with following DAX

DAX

```
Week start date = CALCULATE(Min('Calendar'[Date]),ALLSELECTED('Calendar'))

Week end date =  CALCULATE(Max('Calendar'[Date]),ALLSELECTED('Calendar'))
```

Now I created another measure to count no. of records having Submitted Dates between week start and end dates

```
#Submissions per week = CALCULATE(COUNT('Tracker'[Submitted Date]), DATESBETWEEN('Tracker'[Submitted Date].[Date],[Week start date],[Week end date]))
```

Sample data

| Name | Submitted date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12/09/2022 |
| B | 12/09/2022 |
| C | 12/11/2022 |
| D | 12/12/2022 |
| E | 12/13/2022 |
| F | 12/14/2022 |
| G | 12/10/2022 |
| H | 11/18/2022 |
| I | 12/03/2022 |
| J | 12/07/2022 |
| K | 12/12/2022 |
| L | 12/14/2022 |
| M | 12/14/2022 |
| N | 12/01/2022 |

Total Submissions between 12/04/2022 and 12/10/2022 should be **4** from the above sample data.

But its counting all the records (14) which is not the case. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: try just `COUNT('Tracker'[Submitted Date])` if 'Calendar' and Tracker are linked

Comment: @Mik Tried, but didn't work :(

Comment: what number you got? are Calendar' and Tracker linked?

Comment: Yes, Got count of all records.

Comment: Great! :), nice it helped

Comment: Oh sorry, you misunderstood my comment. I meant I got count of all the records (14) which is not the case here :). I have built relationship (many to one) between submitted date and calendar date. But still didn't work

Comment: then it's not great ).  I'll check your case later on. Is your 'Calendar' made of `CALENDAR()`/`CALENDARAUTO()` ?

Comment: don't forget to replace `tbl` with `Tracker`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

the measure for this:

```
Count = Count(tbl[Submitted date])
```

The calendar is made of:

```
Calendar = CALENDARAUTO()
```

here is a data model:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Similar to #Submissions per week, I have #Hires per week, #Onboarded per week. The approach you stated is filtering my data.

Comment: Hi, if you mean that you have more input conditions, then add it to the question. I see only your sample table and have no idea about your real data model. If you meat that  the issue solved, then you can mark the answer/